# pdo echo error message when invalid username or password is entered

Tags: php, html, pdo

hello i am relatively new to pdo(php) and i created a basic login system i know it is not secure yet but i am just experimenting anyway i know in the old php you could echo out and error message within an if statement but it does not seem to work anymore here is my script is it that im doing something wrong or that you just cant do that in pdo anymore.

```
if ($row == null){

            header( "location: login.html");
            echo "login failed";

        } else{

            header("location: homepage.php");
        }
```

i realize that this may not have enough code available so here is the rest of the script

```
session_start();
    //connection String
    $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=server;Database=database", "username", "password"); 

    //Seelcting function
    $smt = $connection->prepare("select user_id, username from account where username = :username and password =:password");

    //setting values to textboxes
    $username = $_POST["txt_username"];
    $password = $_POST["txt_password"];

    //binding values
    $smt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $smt->bindValue(':password', $password);

    //execution
    $smt->execute();

    //fetching data
    $row = $smt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ;  
    echo "$row[user_id]\n\n";
    echo "$row[username]\n\n";
    $_SESSION{"user_id"} = $row["user_id"];
```

Comment: My guess would be that $row is not null.

Comment: You need to post more code

Comment: Remove `echo` after `header` and put `exit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you send the

```
header( "location: login.html");
```

the browser will redirect to that new file (`login.html`) and ignore (almost) any further output.

Do display the message on `login.html` later on, you have to use some mechanism to transfer the message to that page, e.g., by using a session variable.

**EDIT**

The `header` command send some kind of data to the browser before the actual content. If you make the browser redirect using a header, the user never gets to see the content.

So you need some way of bringing the content to the next page, you are redirecting to.

One possibility would be to use a session variable.

```
if ($row == null){
  $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "login failed";
  header( "location: login.php");
} else{
  header("location: homepage.php");
}
```

In the `login.php` then you could react to this message if it is present:

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['errormsg'] ) ) {
  // do the output
  echo $_SESSION['errormsg'];
  // delete the message from the session, so that we show it only once
  unset( $_SESSION['errormsg'] );
}
```

Comment: How would you go about doing that i am new to the whole programming scene so this kind of confuses me i get what you are getting at but im still confused

Comment: would that involve changing my login.html into login.php so to set the session at he start of it or is this all in long.php?

Comment: @user2416980 Depending on sour server configuration, your `login.html` will maybe be parsed as PHP. In that case you could just drop the respective code in there. Otherwise you need to rename it to `login.php`.